# Renaming Dynamic Block Visibility States using VBA

Tags: vba, autocad

How can I change or rename visibility states for a dynamic block in AutoCAD using VBA, similar to clicking `RENAME` in the Visibility State dialog box which appears when issuing the `BVSTATE` command in the Block Editor?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it is **not** possible to rename Dynamic Block Visibility States directly using the LISP or VBA API, without resorting to invoking standard AutoCAD commands, for example, using the AutoLISP `command` function, or `sendcommand` method.

Dynamic Block Parameters contained within a block definition are not exposed to the ActiveX object model and therefore cannot be modified using Visual LISP or VBA.

Such parameters *are* exposed to Vanilla AutoLISP by examining the DXF data stored within the Extension Dictionary of the `BLOCK_RECORD` entity, but such data cannot be modified using `entmod`, nor does it yield any relevant properties following conversion to an equivalent VLA-Object representation.

---

For what it's worth, you can access the Dynamic Block Parameter DXF data using the following route through the AutoLISP API:

First, obtain the `BLOCK` entity:

```lisp
(setq bl (tblobjname "block" "YourBlockName"))
```

Then obtain the parent `BLOCK_RECORD` entity:

```lisp
(setq br (cdr (assoc 330 (entget bl))))
```

Now obtain the Extension Dictionary from DXF group 360 (additional checks for the presence of `"{ACAD_XDICTIONARY"` against DXF group 102 should be used in production code):

```lisp
(setq d1 (cdr (assoc 360 (entget br))))
```

Now search this dictionary for the `ACAD_ENHANCEDBLOCK` entry:

```lisp
(setq d2 (dictsearch d1 "acad_enhancedblock"))
```

This will yield the DXF data for the `ACAD_EVALUATION_GRAPH` entity.

You can then iterate over the DXF group 360 within the DXF data to obtain the DXF data for each Dynamic Block Parameter found within the block definition, e.g.:

```lisp
_$ (foreach dxf d2 (if (= 360 (car dxf)) (print (cdr (assoc 0 (entget (cdr dxf)))))))

"BLOCKPOLARPARAMETER" 
"BLOCKPOLARGRIP" 
"BLOCKGRIPLOCATIONCOMPONENT" 
"BLOCKGRIPLOCATIONCOMPONENT" 
"BLOCKPOLARSTRETCHACTION" 
"BLOCKFLIPPARAMETER" 
"BLOCKFLIPGRIP" 
"BLOCKGRIPLOCATIONCOMPONENT" 
"BLOCKGRIPLOCATIONCOMPONENT" 
"BLOCKGRIPLOCATIONCOMPONENT" 
"BLOCKFLIPACTION" 
"BLOCKVISIBILITYPARAMETER" 
"BLOCKVISIBILITYGRIP" 
"BLOCKGRIPLOCATIONCOMPONENT" 
"BLOCKGRIPLOCATIONCOMPONENT"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try to do as your instruction.

Comment: @NghiaChau You're most welcome. Please mark my answer as the solution if it answers your question, so that the question appears as resolved to others browsing the site.